# Vertical Black lines between rows HTML! How to fix?

Tags: html, css

I cant find way to solve vertical black lines between rows...

When i use white mode on mail everything is okay,
but when i send mail to phones who have black mode on or apps who have black mode, lines shows up...

Always when i use colspan=2 that happens...

Here is pictures of problem...
I mark Black lines with Red Squares

[image: BlackMode Mail App]

[image: Default WhiteMode]

Here is my code

Thanks! <3

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body background-color="white" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="1000px" heigh="1000px">
<table text-decoration="none !important" id="Table_01" width="450" height="179" border="0 !important" border-color="transparent" cellpadding="0 !important" cellspacing="0 !important" border-collapse="collapse !important" border-spacing="0 !important">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" >
            <img border=0 src="images/infologo.png" width="450" height="92"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img border=0 src="images/mob.png" width="165" height="25"></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img border=0 src="images/pmob.png" width="285" height="25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img border=0 src="images/fiks.png" width="165" height="22"></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img border=0 src="images/social.png" width="285" height="22"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img border=0 src="images/loc.png" width="165" height="19"></td>
        <td>
            <img border=0 src="images/ig.png" width="151" height="19"></td>
        <td>
            <img border=0 src="images/fb.png" width="134" height="19"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img border=0 src="images/site.png" width="450" height="21"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```